# What is wrong in this while loop?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php 
$counter = 1;

while ($counter == 5) {
    echo "foo<br />";
    $counter++;
}
?>
```

What I am expecting is to print *foo* 5 times on a separate lines. But what I get is a never ending loop. Are PHP while loops special? because when I do similar thing in Python, it works fine.

Comment: On when the counter  value will be  get incremented !!!!

Comment: You need `<=` this sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `while ($counter <= 5)`. That means "loop through this as long as `$counter` is less than or equal to `5`".

The way you have it written, it is saying "loop through this as long as `$counter` equals `5`". Since `$counter` is `1` the first time it gets to your loop, it skips the loop entirely!

Comment: Or put differently: `while` runs as long as the expression (between the parentheses) evaluates to `true` and it stops if the expression evaluates to `false`

Answer (score 3):

`$counter == 5` will satisfy only if the counter value reach 5, so it will not print 5 times as expected. So try this code below

```
<?php 
    $counter = 1;

    while ($counter <= 5) {
        echo "foo<br />";
        $counter++;
    }
    ?>
```

[PHP while loop](http://www.in2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) Docs

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is checking for equality which they are not, you should do it like this :-

```
<?php 
    $counter = 1;

    while ( 5 >= $counter ) {
        echo $counter;
        $counter++;
    }
?>
```

And its always better to but the value on left side and a variable on right side, It will sometime save you from Hell...!